# CSS pagebreak for table

Tags: css, gridview, printing, page-break

I had google about the pagebreak in CSS and also get many solution from that, but I has a critical question because I got few table inside my page. Is that possible to break only 1 table? Note that I wanna print gridview in asp.net c#, I put this css because I think that the asp.net will render to html when display in browser. I just wanna insert pagebreak feature for the table (gridview) inside tbody.

```
            table
            {
                page-break-inside: auto;
            }
            tr
            {
                page-break-inside:avoid; 
                page-break-after: auto;
            }
            td
            {
                page-break-inside:avoid; 
                page-break-after: auto;
            }
            thead
            {
                display: table-header-group;
                position: relative;
            }
            tfoot
            {
                display: table-footer-group;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }
```

Comment: If you want the effect ononly one table, then give an id or class to the table you want to have page break and apply your css on that id/class only. Not on all the tables.

Comment: Hi, because I think table my gridview (c#) will auto convert to html table during print, so how I can put the ID in my gridview?

Comment: @HimanshuTyagi if the table call 'gv', how can I put it into print media according to table, tr, td?